# spacy nlp - which algorithms, apis from spacy NLP are not thread-safe?

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

Are all algorithms and APIs from Spacy NLP are thread-safe?

If no, then which are those that are not thread-safe?

If yes, can we specify the thread pool size?

Comment: DId you get the answer ? Is `nlp = spacy.load('en'); nlp(text)` thread safe ?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that workers created with python multiprocessing have properties that are passed by value, which means that the tagging/parsing models are duplicated. So, multithreading dilutes the entire purpose of increasing efficiency

Instead, consider calling `nlp.pipe`, which is a multithreaded call to the spaCy pipeline, instead of multi-threading the call to nlp.

```
    for doc in nlp.pipe(texts, n_threads=16, batch_size=10000):
        #do something to process the doc
```